# jQuery: How to keep a DIV at the top of the screen AND restore its position after scrolling up (and reaching its original position)

Tags: jquery, scroll

I want a div element to do something similar to gmail.

- When scrolling down, once gmail's menu (Archive, Spam, Delete...etc) reaches the the top of the screen, it stays there.
- When scrolling up, the menu returns to it's original position.

Another sample is the side bar of this page: [sample 2](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/nomination-judge-the-net-magazine-awards/#blog)

How to achieve that with a simple (and easy to understand) jQuery code?
(Compatible with all browsers)

```
<div id="header">Menu goes here =)</div>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Specific to your problem, try this:

CSS:

```
#header.floating {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $(window).scroll( function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('#header-wrapper').offset().top)
            $('#header').addClass('floating');
        else
            $('#header').removeClass('floating');
    } );

} );
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/omarjuvera/0p9p43Lz/

Comment: +1 Very cool.  However, you might want to post the code as links to sites are frowned upon sometimes because if the site goes down....

Comment: Plus, if you turn this into a plugin that would be a (very) useful tool.

Comment: with this code, the menu disappears and re-appears while scrolling down :-( How can it be fixed?  http://www.punkbunny.com/tmp/scroll/top_n_restore2.html

Comment: Oops, I forgot a really important part: the div that floats needs to be inside a wrapper div. You check ```$(window).scrollTop() > $('#header-wrapper').offset().top``` instead of ```$(window).scrollTop() > $('#header').offset().top```. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: +1 - Great effect. You should share this in the plug-in world

Comment: It is not working well, I tried to wrap my elements into a header-wrapper div, but still is not working, I suggest you to edit your answer and add a jsfiddle link if it is possible

Comment: BE CAREFUL the link above seems to go to a spam/scam/malware type site

Answer (score 4):

A better way of doing this is using jquery waypoints.
Please have a look at this [sticky-elements example](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/)

Also, here is the [getting started](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/) section to the waypoints plugin.

As you can see when scrolling down, the menu sticks to the top screen.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: since the link does not work anymore, would you mind adding your answer as a code?

Comment: Thanks for updating the links. What if the links "die" again? Would you like to add your code as part of the answer?

Comment: I doubt they will vanish again. The developer has updated the website and that changed the links to its plugin. So, no worries.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<script>
var name = "#floatMenu";
var menuYloc = null;
$(document).ready(function(){
        menuYloc = parseInt($(name).css("top").substring(0,$(name).css("top").indexOf("px")))
        $(window).scroll(function () { 
            offset = menuYloc+$(document).scrollTop()+"px";
            $(name).animate({top:offset},{duration:1000,queue:false});
        });
});
</script>
```

And some CSS for the floating DIV called floatMenu:

```
#floatMenu { position:relative; width:100%px; top:0px; left:0px; }
```

And a DIV that floats:

```
<div id="floatMenu">Your content</div>
```

It hasn't quite got the same effect as the example you gave us. This one is animated and chases you down the screen...